# Java: how to access the parent JFrame's methods within the Jpanel

Tags: java, swing

my JFrame and JPanel are two separate classes, my JFrame uses the JPanel as its own content pane. Inside the JPanel, when a certain button is clicked I want to set the visibility of the JFrame to false. I don't get how to access the JFrame's methods within the JPanel though. help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor(java.awt.Component)), which will return the `Window` in which the component is contained, or `null` if the component has no parent `Window`

`JFrame` is a descendent of `Window`, so you cal freely call `setVisible` on the returned `Window`